# How to collect user information from Microsoft Health BOT

Tags: botframework

I am developing a bot using Microsoft BOT Framework v4. I would like to collect user information and answers to a few questions during the chat. I read a few articles which seem very complicated as they use user profile class etc.

I wanted to know if there was a simpler way to do this? Is there a way to collect data from cards or adaptive cards?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the waterfall dialogs from which you can get the information needed  from the user.

or

you can use the input form from the adaptive card.

ex:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": 2,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Tell us about yourself",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "size": "Medium"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "We just need a few more details to get you booked for the trip of a lifetime!",
                            "isSubtle": true,
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Don't worry, we'll never share or sell your information.",
                            "isSubtle": true,
                            "wrap": true,
                            "size": "Small"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Your name",
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "id": "myName",
                            "placeholder": "Last, First"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Your email",
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "id": "myEmail",
                            "placeholder": "youremail@example.com",
                            "style": "Email"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Phone Number"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "id": "myTel",
                            "placeholder": "xxx.xxx.xxxx",
                            "style": "Tel"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": 1,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Diver_Silhouette%2C_Great_Barrier_Reef.jpg",
                            "size": "auto"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think adaptive card design will fit my design better.